# Forgetful functors from categories of algebra create limits?

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, limits-colimits, functors

After Leinster [states](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) the following lemma (on p. 139):

> Let $F:\mathscr A\to\mathscr B$ be a functor and $I$ a small category. Suppose that $\mathscr B$ has, and $F$ creates, limits of shape $I$. Then $\mathscr A$ has, and $F$ preserves, limits of shape $I$.

he gives a couple of remarks:

> *Since $\mathbf {Set}$ has all limits, it follows that all our categories of algebras have all
>   limits*, and that the forgetful functors preserve them.

First, how does the italicized part follow? If he deduces it from the lemma, then he should mention what functor he means in the italicized part. It is only later that he mentions the functor (the forgetful functor), which is a little confusing, but I'm assuming that he means the same functor when he deduces the italicized part from the lemma - is that right? If so, then is it supposed to be obvious that forgetful functors from categories of algebras always create limits?

> **Remark 5.3.7** There is something suspicious about Definition 5.3.5. It refers
>   to equality of objects of a category, a relation that, as we saw on page 31,
>   is usually too strict to be appropriate. It is almost always better to replace
>   equality by isomorphism. If we replace equality by isomorphism throughout
>   the definition of ‘creates limits’, we obtain a more healthy and inclusive notion.
>
> In the notation of Definition 5.3.5, we ask that if F ◦ D has a limit then there
>   exists a cone on D whose image under F is a limit cone, and that every such
>   cone is itself a limit cone.
>
> [... (omitted) ...]

How is the second paragraph related to the question of having equality insted of isomorphism in the definition of limit creation?

Comment: He definitely means the forgetful functor in the italicized part, but without knowing what a category of algebras is supposed to mean, it's hard to know whether it should be obvious that functors from categories of algebras always create limits.

Comment: @jgon By categories of algebras he means "$\textbf{Grp}, \textbf{Ab}, \textbf{Vect}_k, \textbf{Ring}$, etc."

Comment: Actually it appears to be referring to the specific categories of algebras from Ex 5.3.11 based on a sentence a little earlier in the paragraph. And this claim is then the content of that exercise, so it's not obvious, but it should be doable is the idea I think.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to show that the forgetful functor creates limits for categories of varieties in the sense of [universal algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra). Or a slight generalization that allows things like $\mathbf{Vect}_k$. Though I suspect that $\mathbf{Vect}_k$ can be thought of as a category of varieties with a unary operator for every element of $k$ subject to appropriate relations. I am not a universal algebraist.